# Case of a Prophet / Revered Person in the Quran that says Alhamdullillah

Tags: quran, tafseer

To my curiosity,

Is there any case or narration in the Quran that tells about a person (Prophet or Revered (Real) Person ) who says the dzikir Hamdalah (Alhamdulillah or any other indirect way of saying thank you to God) **just immediately  after** 
something good had happened to him / her ? Quote the surah and verse please.

The reason why I asked this because there was a verse in the Quran (89:15-16) that says: "And as for man, when his Lord tries him and [thus] is generous to him and favors him, he says, "My Lord has honored me."Sahih International But when He tries him and restricts his provision, he says, "My Lord has humiliated me."

What's the difference between saying "Allah has favored me" and Alhamdulillah ? Aren't both acknowledging the favors of Allah? But please answer my main question first.

Regards

Comment: Just for clarification does (14:39) "Praise to Allah , who has granted to me in old age Ishmael and Isaac. Indeed, my Lord is the Hearer of supplication."  count?

Comment: It seems you refer to [89:15-16](http://legacy.quran.com/89/15-16) " "And as for man, when his Lord tries him and [thus] is generous to him and favors him, he says, "My Lord has honored me."Sahih International
But when He tries him and restricts his provision, he says, "My Lord has humiliated me." "

Comment: I think it counts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first verses that come to mind are:

The praise of Ibrahim ():

> Praise to Allah , who has granted to me in old age Ishmael and Isaac. Indeed, my Lord is the Hearer of supplication. ([14:39](http://legacy.quran.com/14/39))

The praise of Sulayman and Dawood ():

> And We had certainly given to David and Solomon knowledge, and they said, "Praise [is due] to Allah , who has favored us over many of His believing servants." ([27:15](http://legacy.quran.com/27/15))

The reaction of Sulayman () on the statement of the ant:

> So [Solomon] smiled, amused at her speech, and said, "My Lord, enable me to be grateful for Your favor which You have bestowed upon me and upon my parents and to do righteousness of which You approve. And admit me by Your mercy into [the ranks of] Your righteous servants." ([27:19](http://legacy.quran.com/27/19))

The reaction of Sulayman () when he asked for the throne of the queen of saba':

> Said one who had knowledge from the Scripture, "I will bring it to you before your glance returns to you." And when [Solomon] saw it placed before him, he said, "This is from the favor of my Lord to test me whether I will be grateful or ungrateful. And whoever is grateful - his gratitude is only for [the benefit of] himself. And whoever is ungrateful - then indeed, my Lord is Free of need and Generous." ([27:40](http://legacy.quran.com/27/40))

These last two statements are the only ones -i know of- giving the impression that the thanking happened immediately after the testing of Sulayman ().

Beside this many verses of the quran use words of praise while refereeing to good people (those who have believed and done righteous deeds) like in ([7:43](http://legacy.quran.com/7/43), [10:10](http://legacy.quran.com/10/10), [35:34](http://legacy.quran.com/35/34), [39:74](http://legacy.quran.com/39/74))

It is also mentioned as one of the kinds of wisdom given to Luqman:

> And We had certainly given Luqman wisdom [and said], "Be grateful to Allah ." And whoever is grateful is grateful for [the benefit of] himself. And whoever denies [His favor] - then indeed, Allah is Free of need and Praiseworthy. ([31:12](http://legacy.quran.com/31/12))

Comment: Umm what I don't understand is what was the test of Solomon exactly?

Comment: @Rextia maybe test in this context is a bit inappropriate, but one could say the Qur'an has a couple of quotes of tests or temptations  Sulayman pbuh has experienced, one of them is that he and his father have been given wisdom, an other is the knowledge of the language of animals he has been given, the leadership over men, Jinn and bird he has been given, his test by the race horses [(38:31)](http://legacy.quran.com/38/31) and the body which was placed on his throne [(38:34)](http://legacy.quran.com/38/34)

Answer (score 3):

As Medi1Saif has already quoted, there are many instances of good people praising and being thankful to Allah in the Quran (14:39, 27:15). And there are many instances of the Prophet (SAW) saying Alhamdulillah, as well. In fact we say Alhamdulillah because it is the Sunnah of the Prophet.

Then, why does Allah criticize the people in 89:15-16? Well here are the ayaat:

> As for man, whenever his Lord tries him and honors and blesses him, he says, "My Lord has honored me." But when He tests him and restricts his provisions for him,. he says, "My Lord has disgraced me."

This is a tafsir of the ayaat:

> This then is man's materialistic view of life. **He regards the wealth and position and power of this world alone as everything**. When he has it, he is filled with pride and says God has honored me; and when he fails to obtain it, he says: God has humiliated me. Thus, the criterion of honor and humiliation in his sight is the possession of wealth and position and power, or the absence of it, **whereas the actual truth which he does not understand is that whatever Allah has given anybody in the world has been given for the sake of a trial.** If he has given him wealth and power, it has been given for a trial to see whether he becomes grateful for it, or commits ingratitude. If he has made him poor, in this too there is a trial for him to see whether he remains content and patient in the will of God and faces his hardships bravely within permissible bounds, or becomes ready to transgress every limit of morality and honesty and starts cursing his God.

So basically, in this Ayah, Allah is criticizing those who think wealth and property in this world is Allah honouring you. And poorness is Allah disgracing you. Allah is saying that both are a test, and doesn't have much to do with what Allah thinks of you. Many bad people are rich, and many good people are poor.

It is not criticizing people for being thankful to Allah. It is criticizing people who think wealth is a show of how much Allah loves you.

Comment: So should we praise Allah SWT for giving the properties and wealth that we have or shouldn't we?

Comment: @Rextia . We should thank Allah for what we have, but we must never think that our wealth is a show of how good we are or our poorness is a show of how bad we are. In fact, I think Christianity used to have this concept that people being rich is a sign of God loving them. That is what this ayah is talking against.

Comment: I would be careful when commenting on other religions without quoting a reference or the source in the Bible that says that...I don't think most people nowadays are that shallow thinking that being rich is a sign of God loving them...and that poor means God hates them..perhaps in a darker past..when there was no internet available...!

Comment: @Rextia . Definitely not now. I was more thinking of Medieval times Catholic Church, and attitude towards Kings. Kings used to have a 'divine right' to rule. And you couldn't rebel against them because God himself is happy with them, and gave them riches.

Comment: What Allah is saying is that you're riches in this world does not mean Allah is happy with you, and they do not mean he is angry with you. Everything is a test. Basically a King is no better than anyone else just because of his riches.