# Prophet / Revered Person in the Quran that says thanks to Allah for protection

Tags: quran, dhikr

Another question but slightly different than the one [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46563/case-of-a-prophet-revered-person-in-the-quran-that-says-alhamdullillah/46570?noredirect=1#comment78103_46570)

Is there any case (narration) in the Quran of a Revered (Real) Person / Prophet who essentially is thanking Allah SWT ( or Alhamdulillah) for protecting him / her or for his protection against any kind of harm?

Note: it doesn't matter here whether is immediately after an incident or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your new question has a smooth transition to your last one therefore some of my quotes may more apply to your earlier question and some may apply to both and some may more likely be a good answer on your actual question.
I think there's also a smooth transition to supplication, as thanking Allah or doing suplication are both a kind of remembrance of Allah.

Secondly note that thanking can be expressed by many things for example the mother of Mariam () expressed her thankfulness for the birth of her -female- child by seeking refuge for her (daughter) in Allah from the Shaytan:

> But when she delivered her, she said, "My Lord, I have delivered a female." And Allah was most knowing of what she delivered, "And the male is not like the female. And I have named her Mary, and I seek refuge for her in You and [for] her descendants from Satan, the expelled [from the mercy of Allah ]." ([3:36](http://legacy.quran.com/3/36))

One could say that she thanked Allah for her child and asked Allah to protect it from any harm, as he protected her during the pregnancy.

The Qur'an also invites us to be thankful for having parents (etc.) in ([31:14](http://legacy.quran.com/31/12)) and being born ([16:78](http://legacy.quran.com/16/78)).

Allah () also asked our Prophet () and his companions () to be thankful after the battle of badr:

> And already had Allah given you victory at [the battle of] Badr while you were few in number. Then fear Allah ; perhaps you will be grateful. ([3:123](http://legacy.quran.com/3/123))

One could say the same about the battle of Hunain ([9:25-27](http://legacy.quran.com/9/25-27)).

Thankfulness can be expressed by a prostration or maybe generally by a worship or good deed like in the story of Dawod() ([38:21-25](http://legacy.quran.com/38/21-25)) (this could also be used as an example for [Case of a Prophet / Revered Person in the Quran that says Alhamdullillah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46563/case-of-a-prophet-revered-person-in-the-quran-that-says-alhamdullillah)?)

One could here add parts of the story of Yusuf () who has been saved from the well, then saved (or guided by Allah) from committing the sin of zina and therefore preferred to be arrested instead (And asked Allah to protect him from zina by imprisonment ([12:33](http://legacy.quran.com/12/33)) and after all Allah brought him together with his family and they expressed their thankfulness in ([12:100-101](http://legacy.quran.com/12/100-101)) because of Allah's protection and gifts over them.

One could also add Ayyub ().

> And [mention] Job, when he called to his Lord, "Indeed, adversity has touched me, and you are the Most Merciful of the merciful." ([21:83](http://legacy.quran.com/21/83))

And Nuh ([23:28](http://legacy.quran.com/23/28))

Some other possible evidences is the reaction of Shu'aib and those who believed him who sought refuge by Allah when the eminent ones wanted to expulse them ([7:85-93](http://legacy.quran.com/7/85-93)).

And Musa () who fled from Pharaoh to Madyan in first place asked Allah to forgive him for having kiled a soul, then refused to assist criminals (Pharaoh), the to save him (from Pharaoh), then to guide him (once in Madyan) then after witnessing what happened at the well he expressed his need of Allah's gift (this final supplication is recommended for those people who seek marriage) ([28:14-24](http://legacy.quran.com/28/14-24)).

Comment: I have no idea why my next question would transition to supplication..CMIIW but AFAIK Hamdalah and Supplication (Du'a) are two very different concepts.. one is thanking Allah SWT for the good things that He has given to us in the "past" and the other is asking for something that has "yet to happen". They are not the same. One cannot replace the other. I don't think they're even similar.

Comment: Although, you did post something of great interest for my next question..(3:123). Regards

Answer (score 1):

There is an implied mention of Noah ﷺ saying so after mounting his vessel prior to the flooding as commanded by Allah:

> فَإِذَا اسْتَوَيْتَ أَنتَ وَمَن مَّعَكَ عَلَى الْفُلْكِ فَقُلِ الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ الَّذِي نَجَّانَا مِنَ الْقَوْمِ الظَّالِمِينَ
>
> And when you have boarded the ship, you and those with you, then say, 'Praise to Allah who has saved us from the wrongdoing people.'
>
> <sub>— [Surat Al-Mu'minun [23:28]](https://quran.com/23/28)</sub>

The verse does not say explicitly that he did, but it is implied as Noah ﷺ obeyed Allah's commands. He obeyed Him building a ship in the middle of the desert and obeyed Him in all the preparations leading to this perilous journey. It is thus implied that as Noah ﷺ saw Allah's promise of the flooding with his own eyes that he would have followed His command in saying "Praise to Allah ...".

Comment: just one example?